# How to read the style (or get html element) of each cell in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

Is there a way to iterate through the [ag-grid](http://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-interfacing-overview/index.php) and get access to the underlying html element (or to the style of it)?

It has `forEachNode(callback)`. But the callback simply gives in params the whole row and the cell values. I need to get hold of the styles of the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can comment so i'll use an answer : it's probably prossible but i don't think the grid has been designed for that.

You can customize the styling of cell, check http://ag-grid.com/angular-grid-cell-styling/index.php. And you can override the css if you want to change the definition of the cell classes.

Comment: Yes - the grid is not designed to be handle in that way. I will upvote for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could always iterate through using JQuery and the count of your rowData and columnDefs. Then each element could be targeted using the "ag-row" or "ag-cell" class.

Comment: Please write to code snippet to access the 3rd row 5th cell as an example.